# Order posts ascending from posts in array

Tags: query, order, sort

I have all my post id's in a specific array `$productIds`. When I want to show only these posts, I do this query:

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'Product',
        'orderby' => "post__in",
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $productIds
        );
```

But this shows all the posts ordered from Z to A. So I've added an array in the orderby:

```
 $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'Product',
        'orderby' => array (
          'post__in' => $productIds,
          'title' => 'ASC'
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
```

All the posts are shown, so not only the ones that are in the array `$productIds`

How do I order alphabetically (A->Z) and only show the ones that are in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'Product',
    'orderby' => "name",
    'order'  => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $productIds
);
```

Comment: `name` would be the slug, so he probably needs `title` instead.